# Initial value for FlutterQuill editor

Tags: flutter, editor, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to insert an initial value to the `flutter_quill` flutter text editor with no success. Link to package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill . From a normal TextField I would have done something like below using the controller.

```
class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
  TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new TextEditingController(text: 'Initial value');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new TextField(
          // The TextField is first built, the controller has some initial text,
          // which the TextField shows. As the user edits, the text property of
          // the controller is updated.
          controller: _controller,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill#usage

Comment: Thank you @pskink , I don't know why I missed that. But one more question, I have my initial value as a string, but I'm required to have it in json. Is there a way for it to accept the string value? Some codes or something. Thank you.

Comment: see https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill#input--output, write some text, call `toJson` end check whats inside, also https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill#configuration has a link with sample configuration - i believe `Document()..insert(0, 'Empty asset');` would simply work

Comment: and here they have some sample json https://github.com/singerdmx/flutter-quill/blob/master/example/assets/sample_data.json - i think lines 2-4 are simply the same as `Document()..insert(0, 'Flutter Quill');` but of course i did not test it

Comment: `Document()..insert(0, 'Flutter Quill');` This one worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert initial text to **Flutter Quill Controller** by using the following statement:

```
    quillController =
        QuillController(document: Document.fromJson([{'insert':'Paste your text here\n'}]),// "\n" is mandatory
         selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0),
    );
```